# How to find out which of components has been clicked from inside of component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Consider i have multiple components of one type like so:

```
<settings type="first">1</settings>
<settings type="second">2</settings>
<settings type="third">3</settings>
<settings type="fourth">4</settings>
<settings type="fifth">5</settings>
```

Each of components is part of "group" called settings, but also each does slightly different job - common thing is that it is setting element.
Now, because each does different job, i have in "settings" component definition multiple methods, but each method behaves differently depending which component was clicked:

```
Vue.component('settings',
    {
        template:  '<div class="setting" @click="selectIt">',
        props: ['type'],
        methods: {
            selectIt() {
               switch ( this.type ) {
                  case 'first':
                  console.log("first")
                  break;
                  case 'second':
                  console.log("second")
                  break;
               }
       }
   }
})
```

Here come questions:

- is this a good way to solve this kind of problem? Maybe each setting should be different kind of component?
- how - in other way - find out which setting was clicked from inside of component?

Comment: passing a prop to the settings component doesn't fit what you need?

Comment: it works, but in many settings components it becomes quite messy, i wonder if there is some better way

Comment: well, on html, you can use v-for and pass the index of the component as a prop, less html, and in terms of logic i prefer do something like case: 1, instead of case 'first'

Comment: i hoped that there is some internal variable in component which says which of the components it is..

Comment: There is another clearner method. Just create a function object of data () {} and assign it to the click event, and it will only be triggered once that component is clicked

Comment: Can you provide some example?

Comment: Can you explain what sorts of different jobs this settings component handles?

Comment: sure. first for examples clears database from users, the second restarts game step and so on.. they do quite different jobs

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/943bx5px/233/ try this edit: you can leave the method{} if you want i am sure there are better and simpler ways to do it

Answer (score 1):

Every component has his own id if it's what you need:

```js
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: '#my-component',
  data() {
    return {
      selected: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    selectMe() {
      this.selected = !this.selected
      console.log(this._uid)
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
})
```

```css
.card {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.selected {
  background-color: #B1B1B1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-component>1</my-component>
  <my-component>2</my-component>
  <my-component>3</my-component>
  <my-component>4</my-component>
  <my-component>5</my-component>
</div>

<template id="my-component">
  <div class="card" :class="{'selected': selected }" @click="selectMe">
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: +1 this is a good one but the `_uid` is integer data and if op wants some other format he would have to resort to the same switch scenario

Answer (score 0):

Probably below solution will meet your requirements.

My opinions:

1. add one prop=handlers, then define default handler to each type
2. if parent component want to execute some special logic, pass one its own handler to the `settings` component. For your case, it seems Parent component knows what need to do, but child component doesn't. So parent pass one handler to child will be better (the child doesn't care about what it is where it is, just need to do its job).

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.component('settings', {
        template:  '<div class="setting" @click="selectIt">{{type}}</div>',
        props: {
          'type':{
            type: String,
            default:'first'
          },
          'handlers':{
            type: Object,
            default: ()=>{ return {} }
          }
        },
        data() {
          return {
            defaultHandlers: { // define your handlers for each type at here
              'first': ()=> {
                console.log('first')
              },
              'second': ()=> {
                console.log('second')
              },
              'third': ()=> {
                console.log('third')
              }
            },
            mergedHandlers: {}
          }
        },
        methods: {
            selectIt() {
               if(this.type in this.mergedHandlers) {
                this.mergedHandlers[this.type]()
               } else { // if handler not found, do something
                console.warn('handler not found')
               }
            }
       },
       mounted: function(){
        // merge customize option with default handlers
        Object.assign(this.mergedHandlers,this.defaultHandlers,this.handlers)
       }
   }
)
app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    message: "Puss In Boots"
  },
  methods: {
    customHandlerForSecond: function () { // pass customized handler to child component
      console.log('parent customized second for ' + this.message)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <settings type="first"></settings>
  <settings type="second" :handlers="{'second':customHandlerForSecond}"></settings>
  <settings type="third"></settings>
  <settings type="fourth"></settings>
  <settings type="fifth"></settings>
</div>
```